# Download zip file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

When my user clicks 'Download app', the zip file downloads to his/her computer.
I want it so that when my user clicks 'Download app', the zip file saves to my server (linux).
[enter link description here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:522c)

Comment: Please post relevant code the link you have posted have n number of lines.

Comment: @khanshahrukh :
   return \Response::download($file, $filename . '.zip', $headers);

Answer (score 0):

There are three things

1. Download file to your server from some online resource
2. Download file to client's computer from your server
3. Upload from client's computer to your server

And as far as I can understand you want the first one, so for that you may get the file with file_get_contents. You may also use curl for that the following is an example with file_get_contents();

```
$file = file_get_contents('url_provided_by_the_user');
$destinationPath = public_path() . '/location/to/save/'.$filename . '.extension';
file_put_contents($destinationPath, $file);
}
```

if by any chance I got confused to understand your question please comment below and I will try to rectify things

Comment: can we talk in Skype?

Comment: I am available on #laravel channel at irc with the username artisanIndia

Comment: please go to this website : www.Puzzley.com (username : hamidreza  pass : 666666) after you login, click the 'apps' in left menu,after click 'untitled App' , then Clik 'Download app' button in above page.the zip file download into your computer, i want ,when user click 'Download app',save zip file to my server (instead of saving in user's computer) - can you understand my friend?:)

Comment: yes I understand and the solution I posted is for the exact thing, but the thing is from where are you getting this zip file ?

Comment: please check this url,i dont exactly,if you see this codes,you found how this zip file generate(where) :http://codeviewer.org/view/code:522c